# Craft Table/Tabular static entry input field

Tags: craft3, entry, field, fieldtypes, table

Is there a way to set up a Craft CMS entry field to have a table with predefined rows and columns?

I have tried with the native Craft Table field, but it allows users to add rows or edit default values. I thought a combination of Super Table and Craft's own Matrix field might work but it doesn't allow for default values.

Essentially I would like a table of rows with a static number of rows I can loop through with 4 distinct columns. One of which would be labels, the other 3 columns would be user input. Is this possible or is there another way to make this happen in a way that I can loop through? Emphasis on ease of user input for a set number of rows/elements, rich text, and using as few field names/handles as possible.